# jQuery .offset if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using jquery .dragable / .dropable on my site.

http://www.chaosdesign.com/production/ernst-young/2014/landingpage/

I want to trigger an event if all items are dropped in the right place - it will basically say "well done you have finished"

The way i was thinking of doing this was by getting the coordinates of the drag item and the drop item and then writing an if statement to say if the .offset values are the same do this.

My current JS

```
var snapPos = $('.word1').offset();
var wordPos = $('.snap1').offset();

if ($(wordPos) == $(snapPos)){
alert("hello");
}
```

But this isnt working.

i also noticed that when i just do an alert for the var snapPos or wordPos the value returned is [object Object]. I was expecting it to return an X/Y coordinate? is this correct?

Thanks

**EDIT**

```
var snapPos = $('.snap1').offset().top.left;
var wordPos = $('.word1').offset().top.left;

if (wordPos == snapPos){
alert("hello");
}
```

Comment: Why using `$`? why not `wordPos == snapPos` directly?

Comment: use the droppable's `drop` function to get an event call when an acceptable element is dropped on the appropriate element http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop

Comment: Bit of a rookie, thanks for pointing that out. Ive changed but it still isnt working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the droppable [drop](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#event-drop) event with the [accept](http://api.jqueryui.com/droppable/#option-accept) option set to get a event call back when an acceptable element is dropped on the appropriate element

```
$( ".selector" ).droppable({ 
   accept: ".someDraggable",
   drop:function( event, ui ) {
      console.log(".someDraggable was dropped on me");
   }
});
```

The problem with your code is you are trying to compare two objects against each other. And unless they exactly the same object it will always return false. Example:

var a = {
   letter:"a"
};
var b = {
   letter:"a"
};

```
if(a==b) {
   //will never be reached as even though the contents of the 
   //object match the objects themselves do not.
}
```

You would either need to do as i suggest and use the built in events that jquery-ui has for handling these kinds of things or test the individual properties of the offset object of both elements against each other

//Get the underlying dom element and then use getBoundingClientRect() to get their 
//position and size information
var snapRect = $('.snap1')[0].getBoundingClientRect(); 
var wordRect = $('.word1')[0].getBoundingClientRect();

```
if( 
    (wordRect.left >= snapRect.left && wordRect.left <= snapRect.right)&&
    (wordRect.top >= snapRect.top && wordRect.top <= snapRect.bottom)
){
  console.log("word1 is within the bounds of snap1");
}
```

`getBoundingClientRect()` returns a object like below:

```
{
   bottom: 406.960205078125
   height: 207.8125
   left: 435.9090881347656
   right: 1103.7215576171875
   top: 199.14772033691406
   width: 667.8125
}
```

Example of checking that all elements have been dropped

```
var counter = 0;
$( ".selector" ).droppable({ 
   accept: ".someDraggable",
   drop:function( event, ui ) {
      counter++;
      //check that counter is equal to the number of .someDraggable elements on the page.
      if(counter == $('.someDraggable').length){
         console.log("all .someDraggable elements were dropped on me");
      }
   }
});
```

Comment: i need it to perform a function only once all items are dropped in the right place. Thats why i thought i would have to you an if statement?

Comment: @jarrettowen then just keep a counter within the drop event, count how many elements have successfully been dropped against the number of elements on the page, if all have been dropped then execute some other function. I will edit to show an example

Comment: thanks for the post patrick i understand the theory and i think the counter seems the best way to go, but when i add it to my script its not working - probably because what i've done to date is no doubt a very long way round to achieve the same effect. but i'm still a beginner at this jquery lark, any help on my jsfiddle would be greatly appreciated - although to be honest what you've done already is very generous! jsfiddle.net/pf34F/3

Comment: @jarrettowen Look at this [modified jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pf34F/4/), i condensed the droppable calls to a single call to make it more easier to edit. And created 2 functions, one for the accept option and one for the drop event. The accept functions checks that the right element can be used, and the drop function takes the necessary actions when the drop is successful. Also modified the html elements a bit so that the snap* elements also have a `data-accept` attribute which lets the accept function know which class is acceptable.

Comment: Counter works great but now my .addclass 'tick' has stopped working and the lightboxes arent loading in. i think it must be the .closest isnt working? Heres the in prog live link: http://www.chaosdesign.com/production/ernst-young/2014/landingpage/v2/index4.html appropriate your help!

Comment: ive fixed the tick by changing
snap.closest(".tick").fadeIn(500);
to: snap.closest(".rowWrap").find(".tick").fadeIn(500); Just the missing lightboxes now :-)

Comment: @jarrettowen add a data-lightbox="" attribute to the span's like i did with the data-accept, and put the appropriate filename/path in them, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the top offset, you need to use:

```
var snapPos = $('.word1').offset().top; // $('.word1').offset().left to get left offset
var wordPos = $('.snap1').offset().top;
```

Then change your code of if condition to:

```
if (wordPos == snapPos){
    alert("hello");
}
```